# Trouble with Google charts getting this.J[a].c is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm VERY new to google charts and I cant seem to find the problem in my code:

My php file returns:

> {"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Time","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Max","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Average","type":"number"}],"rows":[[{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:38:00"},{"v":2576},{"v":2144}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:39:00"},{"v":1960},{"v":1682}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:40:00"},{"v":1789},{"v":1565}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:41:00"},{"v":1995},{"v":1654}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:42:00"},{"v":14647},{"v":11638}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:43:00"},{"v":7512},{"v":5202}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:44:00"},{"v":2056},{"v":1681}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:45:00"},{"v":1874},{"v":1524}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:46:00"},{"v":1706},{"v":1385}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:47:00"},{"v":2244},{"v":1667}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:48:00"},{"v":16198},{"v":13145}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:49:00"},{"v":17549},{"v":13886}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:50:00"},{"v":1824},{"v":1513}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:51:00"},{"v":2299},{"v":1762}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:52:00"},{"v":20273},{"v":13167}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:53:00"},{"v":3024},{"v":2231}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:54:00"},{"v":14386},{"v":10450}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:55:00"},{"v":16368},{"v":13741}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:56:00"},{"v":4528},{"v":2717}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:57:00"},{"v":3655},{"v":2601}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:58:00"},{"v":3456},{"v":2624}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-11-19
>   14:59:00"},{"v":4818},{"v":2917}]}]]}

I would like to draw a graph that plots time  on x and then two lines with MAX and AVERAGE values.
I believe the issue Lies somewhere in my HTML/JAVASCRIPT code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard</title><meta name=keywords /><script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

    <!---->
    <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color: #ffffff; padding-left: 1%; padding-bottom: 100px; }
            footer{font-size:small;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px;}
    </style>
    <style>h1 {color:white; font-size:24pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif }.menu {color:white; font-size:12pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold }table2 {background:black }p {color:black; font-size:12pt; text-align:justify;font-family:arial,sans-serif }p.foot {color:white; font-size:9pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold }a:link, a:visited, a:active {color:white} 
   </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load("visualization", "1", {"packages":["corechart"]});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
$.ajax({
    url: "get_sql_data.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jsonData) {
        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }
});
}
</script>

<!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div><table width=100% bgcolor=black cellpaddin g=0 border=0>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your json data are in bad format. `cols` are ok:

```
{
"cols":
    [
        {
        "id":"", "label":"Time",
        "type":"string"
        },
```

`rows` have one extra pair `[ ... ]` which should be removed:

```
"rows":
    [
        [
            {
                "c":[
                    {"v":"2013-11-19 14:38:00"},
                    {"v":2576},
                    {"v":2144}
                    ]
            },
```

To get

```
"rows":
    [
            {
                "c":[
                    {"v":"2013-11-19 14:38:00"},
                    {"v":2576},
                    {"v":2144}
                    ]
            },
```

See also [Google line chart visualization with JSON blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472672/google-line-chart-visualization-with-json-blob).